# Expression in SSRS not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I have an SSRS report which I want to sum values of a field, but only if the value of another field is equal to 1, as I have made the report output a row number for each row. Bascially, I'm trying to sum the distinct values to come up with a total. Screenshot below. I'm getting an error for orders with more than 1 item. My expression used to calculate the Ship Cost (red text) is as follows

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!WEIGHT.Value, 0))
```

[image]

But I'm getting the #Error. The cell that has the text #Error should be reading $11.25.

Comment: How are you ensuring that the expression looks only at the rows for a given Order #?

Comment: I believe that is covered by the grouping in the report, the row is grouped on Order #. The correct value is displaying for the second order, so it does appear to be looking at that given order.

Comment: It looks like a _formatting_ issue. What is the datatype of Fields!Weight.Value field? Try this `=SUM(IIF(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, CDBL(Fields!WEIGHT.Value), 0.0))` . If that doesn't work Try `=SUM(CDBL(Fields!WEIGHT.Value))` and see if you still get errors and attack the problem from there.

Comment: Hi @Anup Agrawal, you are correct in that it was a data conversion issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're likely getting a datatype mismatch in the aggregate; SSRS can't handle implicit conversions in these sort of `IIf`/aggregate expressions.

In your expression, `0` will be treated as an **int**, and assuming the underlying data type of `Fields!WEIGHT.Value` is **decimal** or **double**, this will throw a runtime error - if you preview in BIDS it should actually display the error.

To get around this you need to make sure the two `IIf` results have the same datatype - something like:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!WEIGHT.Value, 0.0))
```

or

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!WEIGHT.Value, CDec(0)))
```

or

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!WEIGHT.Value, CDbl(0)))
```

Depending on the underlying datatype you may have to try a few combinations but hopefully one of the examples will work correctly,

Comment: Hey @Ian Preston, that was it! It was a data conversion issue. The second statement you gave me did the trick. Thanks so much, such a simple issue that was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.bidn.com/forums/microsoft-business-intelligence/reporting-services/589/how-to-sum-at-group-level

If your group is called "Order#", your expression should be:
`=SUM(IIF(Fields!RowNumber.Value = 1, Fields!Weight.Value, 0),"Order#")`