# SQL sum one value for each unique value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table like this:

```
------------------------------
|id    |duration |date       |
|1     |20       |1392479451 |<--
|2     |20       |1392479451 |
|3     |10       |1392478620 |<--
|4     |30       |1392479457 |<--
|5     |30       |1392479457 |
|6     |30       |1392479457 |
------------------------------
```

I only want to `SUM` the first of each unique `date`:

```
----------------
|SUM(duration) |
|60            |
----------------
```

How do I do this, please?

Comment: you need to use `group by date` at your query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT SUM(duration) FROM (
    SELECT duration FROM tbl GROUP BY date
) t;
```

The `GROUP BY` in the inner query will select only one row per distinct date. Which row will be selected is not defined, but it doesn't matter as the durations should be identical. Then we just sum the durations.

**EDIT**: Just to be clear, this will not select the *first* duration, but *any* single duration for a given date. If the durations can vary within a date and you specifically need the first one, this will not solve your problem.

Comment: This uses a MySQL extension that the documentation explicitly warns against using.  In the subquery, there is no guarantee that `duration` is the "first" record for the `date`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think I was clear on that point. My understanding is that `duration` doesn't vary within a given date.

Comment: . . Nothing in the question suggests that `duration` needs to be unique for each date.  If so, you might as well `group by date, duration` and avoid the need for non-standard SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The sample data suggests it. As far as the use of non-standard SQL, I would say it's ultimately a matter of preference. Personally, I'm comfortable using it, and I prefer the shorter `GROUP BY` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(`date` = ( SELECT MIN(`date`) FROM table WHERE `date` = t.`date`), `duration`, 0))    
FROM `table` t
```

Or

```
SELECT SUM(t1.`duration`) 
FROM `table` t1 
JOIN ( SELECT MIN(`id`) AS `id` FROM `table` GROUP BY `date` ) t2 ON t1.`id` = t2.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first date.  There are several ways, but because MySQL supports silent conversion of strings to numbers, you can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick -- so long as the values on each date do not cause the intermediate string to overflow (you would need a lot of values).

The following should do what you want:

```
select sum(duration + 0)
from (select substring_index(group_concat(duration order by id), ',', 1) as duration
      from table t
      group by date
     ) t;
```

Otherwise, you need an additional `join`:

```
select sum(duration)
from table t join
     (select min(id) as id
      from table t
      group by date
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(duration)
FROM
    datetable d,
    (SELECT 
        date, MIN(id) AS id
    FROM
        datetable
    GROUP BY date) d2
WHERE
    d.id = d2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [Trying to sum distinct values SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218108/trying-to-sum-distinct-values-sql):

```
SELECT SUM(duration) FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT date, duration FROM table)
```