# Get sum of column with distinct id in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get sum of the amount on distinct ext_id.

| Id | Ext_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | 5 |
| 2 | 234 | 5 |
| 3 | 235 | 10 |
| 4 | 236 | 8 |
| 5 | 236 | 8 |

`Select SUM(amount) from Table1` -- this will get me sum of all  => 36

I want just sum of distinct Ext_id which should be 23. Can someone help me with this? THanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to sum distinct values SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218108/trying-to-sum-distinct-values-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(avg_amount)
from (select ext_id, avg(amount) as avg_amount
      from t
      group by ext_id
     ) x
```