# Select sum for filed with all value is 1 results different with number or rows

Tags: mysql, select, sum, distinct

This is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT murid.ID,  
CASE WHEN ..... AS Jumlah
FROM murid
JOIN ... 
JOIN ...
WHERE ....
```

It results 15 rows with 'Jumlah' has all value is '1'.

When I add sum for Jumlah like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT murid.ID,... 
SUM(CASE WHEN ..... ) AS Jumlah
FROM murid
JOIN ... 
JOIN ...
WHERE ....
```

It results Jumlah with value 28.
I only add sum but it result different value.

This value of '28' seems number of rows when I remove DISTINCT.

Somebody please help me, thanks

Comment: Remove DISTINCT in 1st query.

Comment: When i remove distinct in first query it result 28 rows, but it contains some rows with same ID, i need unique ID, and it should results 15 rows

Comment: close by this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218108/trying-to-sum-distinct-values-sql